# Set Default Template for right-click -> new-presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

thanks for having a look at my question!

**What I want to achieve:**
I have a Powerpoint template (.potx) that includes a specific theme and layout ("slide master"), that has my company's logo and branding, so I want to use it as a default for all the new presentation I make (even if I create them using the right-click menu in windows).

**What I did:**

1. In the windows file explorer, I added the .potx file it to my custom office templates in the path

   > C:\Users\...\Documents\Custom Office Templates
2. I set it as default theme in Powerpoint.

[image: screenshot]

**What happened:**
It works fine when I open a new file by going to *File->New*. Then, I can see the default template as the first option.

[image: screenshot]

But still, in file-explorer, when I `right-click` `->` `new` `->` `Powerpoint`, the new presentation that's opened is just a regular "blank" template. I need to manually change the theme, and then the layout of the first slide that's automatically generated.

**Problem:**
How can I set the default theme to to apply when I `right-click` `->` `new` `->` `Powerpoint`?

[image: screenshot]

I open almost all my new presentations with a right-click; I find it better for my style of work, because there's less confusion with save paths of multiple projects, and I have a prepared path for quick saving right from the first second of working on the presentation, so I'd really like to do that with the template if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround to force new presenations via right-click -> new -> Presenation to use the theme you want and include your company's logo and branding.

Please go to `Registry Editor > Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptx\PowerPoint.Show.12\ShellNew`, then check the value of File Name.

On my computer with Microsoft 365 apps installed, the value is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\Windows\ShellNew\powerpoint.pptx`.

[image]

You may locate the ShellNew folder on your computer. Please note, this folder is ready-only. So you could create a .pptx file as your needs and drag it into ShellNew folder to replace the previous one.

(I also suggest you drag the previous "powerpoint.pptx" out first as a backup.)

[image]

Comment: VERY useful answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Definitely solved. Works perfectly.
Thank you so much!
(I don't have enough reputation to vote yet)

Answer (score 0):

*This is a problem common to Office applications where a new file is created in the Windows right-click menu.* It certainly happens with Word where a customized Normal template is ignored.

Try, after you do that, and have PowerPoint open using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl`+`N`. That should give you your default theme.

What I do, instead, is pin PowerPoint to the TaskBar. Clicking on that gives me the Backstage New dialog. Right-clicking on it gives me a recent files list.

Comment: Thanks.

The `ctrl`+`N` file has no save path associated with it, like the first file I opened.
So basically I have to choose whether I open a new file with the correct theme, and manually input the save path, or open a file with the correct save path, but manually have to input the theme?

Comment: So your goal is both to use your default template and to save in a particular file? You could put a macro in your template to intercept the FileSave command and give you the save path to a standard location for that template. I do not know if that improves things. (I have done this with Word, but not with PP.)

Comment: nah, the saving location isn't standard, only the template.
Thanks though. (BTW I don't have enough credits to cast votes, otherwise I would have upvoted your answer. At least it's the first time someone said that's is a recognized issue)

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Alas, the only way to trap events like File Save in PPT is to install the needed code in an add-in. It wouldn't work in a template.